# Regular expression required

Tags: regex

Please give me one regular expression which mathes these kind of name formats like:

1) M/S.KHALIL WARDE S.A.L.

2) Oliver Twist

The expression should allow alphabets, dot, space and / only.

thanks

Comment: What did you tried? You can use [RegexBuddy](http://gofrom.us/4Q6) to help building regular expressions.

Comment: Pleast post what you have tried, we are here to help you. Not to do your job for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
^[A-Za-z. /]+$
```

That matches uppercase `A-Z`, lowercase `a-z`, dot, space, and slash. The `+` means repeated one or more times (so this won't match an empty string). The leading `^` and trailing `$` means the match is "anchored" to the start and end of the string, so it will check your whole string.

Comment: You're just encouraging him or her not to try to figure things out !

Comment: I added an explanation, hopefully that will help.

Comment: Hi Greg, I tried this and it worked ^[a-zA-Z\s\/\-\.]* ..  Thanks your solution is simpler than this